# Why does a large enterprise-level implementation of ExtJs crash every browser?

Tags: javascript, extjs, enterprise, frontend

I are working on a implementation of ExtJs that I think is larger than its makers expected. Our pages instantiate over a 1000 ExtJs components.

This first issue is that, most of the time, a single page load is taking 20-30 seconds to return; during that time the browser displays a spinny wheel indicating that some resource is being used. Except that we are monitoring ram, hard drive, processor and network usage, and none of them are taxed. The server has completed it's request, so the delay is clearly being caused by ExtJs.

The second issue is that after a few clicks, Firefox displays a "slow script" error, Chrome displays a "Kill Page" error, and Safari simply crashes.

Again, RAM, Hard Drive, Network and Processor are all barely being used, yet the browser is unable to handle creating the ExtJs components.

Can anyone point me in the right direction towards load balancing ExtJs so that the browser is not so unhappy?

Comment: You could ask it to their support. PS: it is a terrible way of asking questions: only complaints without any details, not helpful at all

Comment: would the right direction be redesigning the pages so you wouldn't be instantiating thousands of components...

Comment: enterprise-level... shudder. (code for needlessly complicated)

Comment: Are you using lazy instantiation (component configs vs. Ext.create(...))?

Comment: Ext.create vs component configs have essentially no performance gain, in fact, it's not even lazy instantiation. The first thing a container does it loop over the configurations and create objects out of them.

Comment: Yeah but if the component is not visible (I hope you don't have all those 1000+ components visible at the same time on the same page?), it doesn't get rendered. That's where you have performance gain.

Comment: How did it even get to a point where it suddenly crashes like that? Just remove the code which started causing that and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas yall, and welcome to more! It's inherited code so we can't simply "go back to when it worked." The components are visible when they are instantiated, and we are seeing no performance gain from lazy instantiation. Thanks again for the ideas. We will keep working on it!