# Class-based frameworks in Javascript cause browser to hang

Tags: javascript, extjs, frameworks, backbone.js

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772608/why-does-a-large-enterprise-level-implementation-of-extjs-crash-every-browser) earlier about large implementations of EXT crashing the browser.

I have now found this to be the case of backbone and three.js as well. It seems that every Class-based javascript library has a built-in scalability constraint, because there is no way to throttle code loading.

In each of these cases the thing that hangs the browser is class instantiation, not the object instantiation. Even EXT's "lazy load" only delays the objects from being instantiated, not the classes and the browser crash often comes before EXT has even started the object instantiation phase.

Backbone tries to resolve this problem by separating code into views, but just try to load too much code per view and watch it crash.

I am not trying to be obtuse here. When I ask 'what happens when you instantiate 1000 EXT components' and I get the response, 'don't instantiate that many,' the responders are simply missing the point.

It doesn't matter What the code is, it is a question of what the scalability limits are.

And in EXT, Backbone and many other JS frameworks, Class-based instantiation is not load-balanced.

How can class-based frameworks be structured to not instantiate all the classes at once?

But in a browser, script load time is a limited resource and heavily class-based systems must compile all at once, and this is clear scalability problem with every class-based javascript framework: EXT. Backbone, Three.js and many more.

Can anyone address how these frameworks can be made scalable?

Any help appreciated

Comment: What, exactly, is the question here?

Comment: updated with a more specific question, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide example code that causes said crash?  Which browsers?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not provide sample code. I am talking about a comparison of several 4000+ line applications. Please do read my previous question. :)

Comment: I have limited experience with EXT, none with three.js, and some with Backbone, but not at the scale you're discussing.  I'm working on a large single-page application (custom framework, more like Knockout), and have not run into these issues.  Do you really need to create all these objects up front?  Our application creates only those needed for the currently visible view.  Can you not do something similar?  And comparing with jQuery is not really fair.  jQuery is a DOM wrapper with some CSS, some AJAX, and a few ohter utility libraries thrown in.  It does not try to do what Ext tries.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for anyone to help you unless you can tell us precisely what your problem is. Perhaps you should write a mock fiddle which recreates the problem. Try using [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/ "Benchmark.js").

Comment: Also note that your previous question on a similar topic was closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Which browser? I've written a Backbone.js app with several thousand lines of JavaScript without any problems crashing, but we only support newer versions of IE. It seems odd you're having this problem with different JavaScript libraries. The ones you mentioned are rock solid and widely used. Perhaps there's some practice or technique you use that's causing this.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are right, i removed the bit about jQuery.

Comment: It seems like you sure made a mess using so many libraries. Most of the time basic JavaScript knowledge is enough. Massive libraries like jQuery and ExtJS just waste memory. If you really need a library [Microjs](http://microjs.com/# "Microjs: Fantastic Micro-Frameworks and Micro-Libraries for Fun and Profit!") has what you want.

Comment: I will try to explain better: It is not a question of What the code is, it is a question of What happens when too much code is loaded. It is a scalability question, not a style question. I can create this problem with multiple load testing/benchmarking programs. Simply try.

Comment: How many lines of code are you loading? I created a WebGL game with approximately 30000 lines of code and I don't see any scalability issues in any of the browsers I tested it with. Mind you there are tons of active objects that I instantiated.

Comment: @AaditMShah I appreciate your advice. It would be difficult to calculate the exact number of lines. it could easily be 30k+. I can personally attest that it is solid code.

Comment: And I can personally attest that the moon is made of cheese. I've been part of massive web applications that are not only tens of thousands of lines of code long, and instantiate over 50 thousand of objects on some data fetches. And it works fine, with little delay. Sounds like you don't know how to effectively utilize the libraries that are at your disposal, or have incredibly fat, unoptimized code.

Comment: @Stephen I appreciate your candor and can understand how thinking I am simply a bad programmer satisfies your mis-understanding of the question.

Comment: I don't think you're a bad programmer - I know a lot of great programmers who misunderstand how javascript at its core works. The question you've provided does not give anyone any solid leads to help you with, so we're left with just "ok, so he's doing something wrong".

Comment: I get it. So in order to discuss the problem, I must provide the exact benchmarking code to demonstrate the crash. I can do that, and likely will, but I've already demonstrated it "in the wild." I'm happy to endure the "poor implementation" bashes, but they do not stop the spinny wheel. Again, thank you for any advice.

Comment: @BishopZ - I don't know anything about your code, but your inability to ask an answerable question and especially your inability to see why it is unanswerable make your claims of solidity dubious. Many people have scaled browser-based applications that are much larger than yours.

Comment: @lwburk I have no shortage of humility, but scalability questions are not about architecture.

Answer (score 4):

4000 lines of code is not much at all. And browser crashing usually means endless self-sustaining loops which bounce one into another consuming all available memory, so generally speaking, here are some possible reasons:

- non-namespaced framework's name collisions
- overloading prototypes with functions, and iterating through circular objects
- poor implementation

To debug,

1. grab a development copy of each framework
2. set some breakpoints into the guilty constructors
3. Use a javascript profiler to see exactly what happens

Comment: I appreciate your advice and definitely see how it could be good advice for others. I can personally attest that this is not a case of "poor implementation."

Comment: @BishopZ If you want to test if those frameworks are designed to work together, just take your whole app out of the equation and try to instantiate an object. If it crashes the browser, it means you have to bring in changes to how those frameworks work. ExtJS (v3 back in the days) used to have adapters for every other framework or so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your response. Can you explain further?

Comment: I meant: recreate the conditions in which the browser crashes, but do it without including any scripts of your app. Just the libraries and a test.js file. Also this http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0.zip check out the `adapter` folder.

Comment: Yes, that is the conclusion of the comment thread as well. In order to discuss said problem, you must provide benchmarking code to demonstrate said problem. I had hoped that people would address the logical issue: which is that any part of a javascript framework that does not load balance is a potential scalability problem (which can be easily demonstrated).

Comment: Maybe I should post my question to StackMathematica instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I don't think the class/object distinction is relevant in this context. As far as JavaScript is concerned, everything is an object. "Classes" are just higher-level concepts that certain frameworks like ExtJS allow you to work with.

> Even EXT's "lazy load" only delays the objects from being instantiated, not the classes

ExtJS 4 does have the ability to only load classes [when they're needed](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system/) (by making AJAX requests).